# Google Code Jam (Milkshakes) solution

Tags: java, programming-challenge

For practice, I am working through some Google Code Jam problems.  The code below is for the Milkshakes problem, which is located [here](http://code.google.com/codejam/contest/dashboard?c=32016#s=p1).

> **Problem**
>
> You own a milkshake shop. There are N different flavors that you can
>   prepare, and each flavor can be prepared "malted" or "unmalted". So,
>   you can make \$2N\$ different types of milkshakes.
>
> Each of your customers has a set of milkshake types that they like,
>   and they will be satisfied if you have at least one of those types
>   prepared. At most one of the types a customer likes will be a "malted"
>   flavor.
>
> You want to make \$N\$ batches of milkshakes, so that:
>
> There is exactly one batch for each flavor of milkshake, and it is
>   either malted or unmalted. For each customer, you make at least one
>   milkshake type that they like. The minimum possible number of batches
>   are malted. Find whether it is possible to satisfy all your customers
>   given these constraints, and if it is, what milkshake types you should
>   make. If it is possible to satisfy all your customers, there will be
>   only one answer which minimizes the number of malted batches.
>
> Input
>
> - One line containing an integer \$C\$, the number of test cases in the
>     input file.
>
> For each test case, there will be:
>
> - One line containing the
>     integer \$N\$, the number of milkshake flavors.
> - One line containing the
>     integer \$M\$, the number of customers.
> - \$M\$ lines, one for each customer, each containing:
>
>   - An integer \$T >= 1\$, the number of milkshake types the
>       customer likes, followed by
>   - \$T\$ pairs of integers "X Y", one for each
>       type the customer likes, where \$X\$ is the milkshake flavor between 1 and
>       \$N\$ inclusive, and \$Y\$ is either 0 to indicate unmalted, or 1 to indicated
>       malted. Note that:
>
>     - No pair will occur more than once for a single
>         customer.
>     - Each customer will have at least one flavor that they like
>         (\$T >= 1\$).
>     - Each customer will like at most one malted flavor. (At most
>         one pair for each customer has \$Y = 1\$).
>
> All of these numbers are separated by single spaces.
>
> **Output**
>
> - C lines, one for each test case in the order they occur in the input
>     file, each containing the string "Case #X: " where X is the number of
>     the test case, starting from 1, followed by:
>
>   - The string "IMPOSSIBLE",
>       if the customers' preferences cannot be satisfied; OR
>   - N space-separated integers, one for each flavor from 1 to N, which are 0
>       if the corresponding flavor should be prepared unmalted, and 1 if it
>       should be malted. Limits
>
> **Small dataset**
>
> \$C = 100\$
>   \$1 <= N <= 10\$
>   \$1 <= M <= 100\$
>
> **Large dataset**
>
> \$C = 5\$
>   \$1 <= N <= 2000\$
>   \$1 <= M <= 2000\$
>
> The sum of all the \$T\$ values for the customers in a test case will not
>   exceed 3000.

This solution solves for both the small and large data sets.  Please let me know how I can improve this code.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class MilkShake {

  private final int UNMALTED = 0;
  private final int NOCHOICE = 2;
  private boolean isPossible;
  private ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> customerPreferenceList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
  private int[] finalBatchAr;
  private StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new MilkShake().go();
  }

  public void go() {

  File inputFile = new File("/* File name */");
  BufferedReader br = null;

    try {

      br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));    
      int numTests = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

      //Loop through each test
      for(int testCounter = 0; testCounter < numTests; ++testCounter) {
        customerPreferenceList.clear();
        int numFlavors = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        initializeFlavorAr(numFlavors);

        int numCustomers = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        isPossible = true;

        //For each test, loop through each customer
        for(int customerCounter = 0; customerCounter < numCustomers; ++customerCounter) {
          String[] customerPrefs = br.readLine().split(" ");
          ArrayList<Integer> custRow = new ArrayList<Integer>();

          for(int j = 0; j < customerPrefs.length; ++j) {
            custRow.add(Integer.parseInt(customerPrefs[j]));
          }
          customerPreferenceList.add(custRow);
        }

        //Eliminate first element of each row. Number of elements each customer likes is not used.
        if(!customerPreferenceList.isEmpty()) {
          for(ArrayList<Integer> a : customerPreferenceList) {
            if(!a.isEmpty()) { a.remove(0); }
          }
        }

        boolean customerPreferenceListChanged = true;

        while(customerPreferenceList.size() > 0 && isPossible && customerPreferenceListChanged == true) {
          customerPreferenceListChanged = false;
          ArrayList<Integer> removeList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

          //Deal with rows with only one choice
          for(int oneChoiceCounter = 0; oneChoiceCounter < customerPreferenceList.size(); ++oneChoiceCounter) {
            if(customerPreferenceList.get(oneChoiceCounter).size() == 2) {
              int indexOfFlavorInQuestion = customerPreferenceList.get(oneChoiceCounter).get(0);
              if(finalBatchAr[indexOfFlavorInQuestion - 1] == NOCHOICE) {
                finalBatchAr[indexOfFlavorInQuestion - 1] = customerPreferenceList.get(oneChoiceCounter).get(1);
                removeList.add(oneChoiceCounter);
                customerPreferenceListChanged = true;
              }
              else if(finalBatchAr[indexOfFlavorInQuestion - 1] != customerPreferenceList.get(oneChoiceCounter).get(1)) {               
                isPossible = false;
                break;
              }
              else {
                //flavor already in map - remove from customerPreferenceList
                removeList.add(oneChoiceCounter);
                customerPreferenceListChanged = true;
              }
            }
          }

          if(!removeList.isEmpty()) {
            cleanUpCustomerPreferenceList(removeList);
            removeList.clear();
          }

          //Loop through all other cases, if any element already in finalBatchAr remove the row from customerPreferenceList
          for(int elementExistsCounter = 0; elementExistsCounter < customerPreferenceList.size(); ++elementExistsCounter) {
            for(int j = 0; j < customerPreferenceList.get(elementExistsCounter).size(); j += 2) {
              if(finalBatchAr[customerPreferenceList.get(elementExistsCounter).get(j) - 1] == customerPreferenceList.get(elementExistsCounter).get(j + 1)) {
                removeList.add(elementExistsCounter);
                customerPreferenceListChanged = true;
                break;
              }
            }
          }

          if(!removeList.isEmpty()) {
            cleanUpCustomerPreferenceList(removeList);
            removeList.clear();
          }

          //Loop through customerPreferenceList again, get rid of all elements that conflicts with finalBatchAr
          //If currentRow empty afterwards, set isPossible to false
          for(int conflictCounter = 0; conflictCounter < customerPreferenceList.size(); ++conflictCounter) {
            int currentRowSize = customerPreferenceList.get(conflictCounter).size();

            for(int j = 0; j < currentRowSize; j += 2) {
              if((finalBatchAr[customerPreferenceList.get(conflictCounter).get(j) - 1] != NOCHOICE) && (finalBatchAr[customerPreferenceList.get(conflictCounter).get(j) - 1] != customerPreferenceList.get(conflictCounter).get(j + 1))) {                
                customerPreferenceList.get(conflictCounter).remove(j);
                customerPreferenceList.get(conflictCounter).remove(j);
                j -= 2;
                currentRowSize -= 2;
                customerPreferenceListChanged = true;
              }
            }

            if(customerPreferenceList.get(conflictCounter).size() == 0) {
              isPossible = false;
              break;
            }

          }
        }

        finalizeFlavorAr(numFlavors);
        appendResult(testCounter + 1, numFlavors);
      }
    } catch(FileNotFoundException fe) {
        fe.printStackTrace();
    } catch(IOException ie) {
        ie.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
          if(br != null) {
             br.close();
          }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }  
    }
    writeResultToFile();
  }

  private void initializeFlavorAr(int numFlavors) {
    finalBatchAr = null;
    finalBatchAr = new int[numFlavors];

    for(int i = 0; i < numFlavors; ++i) {
      finalBatchAr[i] = NOCHOICE;
    }

  }

  private void finalizeFlavorAr(int numFlavors) {
    for(int i = 0; i < numFlavors; ++i) {
      if(finalBatchAr[i] == NOCHOICE) {
        finalBatchAr[i] = UNMALTED;
      }
    }
  }

  private void appendResult(int testCase, int numFlavors) {

    result.append("Case #" + testCase + ": ");

    if(!isPossible) {
      result.append("IMPOSSIBLE");
    }
    else {
      for(int i = 0; i < finalBatchAr.length; ++i) {
        result.append(finalBatchAr[i] + " ");
      }
    }
    result.append("\n");
  }

  private void writeResultToFile() {  
    PrintWriter pr = null;

    try {
      pr = new PrintWriter(new File("/* File name */"));
      pr.print(result);        

    } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if(pr != null) {
          pr.close();
        }
    } 
  }

  private void cleanUpCustomerPreferenceList(ArrayList<Integer> removeList) {
    for(int i = 0; i < removeList.size(); ++i) {
      int removeIndex = removeList.get(i);
      customerPreferenceList.remove(removeIndex - i);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `go()` method is **waaaaaaaayyyyyyyyyyyyyy** to long, break it up in digestible parts. Try to think in different abstraction levels, and don't mix them in one method (e.g. you deal with file input directly, but have a separate method for writing into a file). Follow the [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

You should use extended for loops where possible, e.g.

```
for(int j = 0; j < customerPrefs.length; ++j) {
   custRow.add(Integer.parseInt(customerPrefs[j]));
}

-->

for(String customerPref : customerPrefs) {
   custRow.add(Integer.parseInt(customerPref));
}
```

Comment: thanks for the input.  In your words, why do you think a smaller method is necessarily better than a larger one?  How would you respond to the argument that given a solution that requires steps A, B, and C to complete it is easier to code them sequentially in one function rather than forcing whoever wants to understand the program to jump back and forth in the code between method definitions?  Not saying I disagree with your response, I would just like to hear your opinion.

Comment: The answer is "level of abstraction". If your method needs to do A, B and C to perform a task, it must do it. However if you have to do A1, A2 and A3 in order to do A, you should have a separate method encapsulating these steps, which is called from the top-level method. In your method, you have more or less a comment for every logical step, which are top-level abstractions. Pack the code after every comment a separate method, and call it from `go()`. But all of this is just an application of the Single Responsibility Principle.

Comment: @fiddlesticks Have a read at this great article by Uncle Bob http://blog.objectmentor.com/articles/2009/09/11/one-thing-extract-till-you-drop
You don't have to extract it so much as in the article, but that gives you a good idea. And you don't have to worry about someone having to jump back and forth to understand the code. With more methods (with each method name suggesting the intent) a reader would be skipping the methods he doesn't care about. And that's a very good thing !

Comment: You can't foreach through an array.

Comment: @sproule When A,B,and C are longer than 15 lines of code put together (or more practically when the code starts to [smell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell)), it's easier to jump between different well-named methods than slog through one poorly-named one.

Comment: @Eva: Actully you *can* foreach thru an array.

Answer (score 1):

Move `try/catch/finally` block body to separate method. Its main goal is an error processing, and body is a main functionality, so they have different responsibility.